# Android 7.0 - SD Card formatted as internal storage

Tags: sd-card, 7.0-nougat, insufficient-memory, adoptable-storage

My Wileyfox handset recently upgraded to 7.0 and I'm getting nowhere with their support. My SD card is formatted as "internal storage". Despite over 30GB of free space on the card, I'm unable to add new apps or update existing ones and am getting lack of space error messages instead. I've reviewed the list of first aid options and these don't offer any solutions. I'm already using the SD card formatted as internal (i.e. not portable) storage.

WFox maintain that many apps will now not run on SD cards.

However, I thought that this related to "external" / "portable" SD cards and that formatting the card as internal memory would avoid this issue. WFox won't address this question. If my understanding is wrong, so be it, but it would be helpful if someone can answer this query for me.

Comment: See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) and [search here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adoptable-storage?sort=newest). You can [edit] your question to add inputs once you are done

Comment: Couldn't you just stick it into another device and format it's brains out?